# Elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot have $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ as a subgroup

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Show that an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot have $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ as a subgroup.

We've been told that for this problem, we are not allowed to use Mazur's Theorem. Unfortunately that is the only way I can think to answer this question. It was suggested that a geometric argument can be made. Can someone point me in a proper direction? I was thinking of using Nagell-Lutz to try to show there may be more than 3 elements with an order 2. I'm not sure it can be done though.

Comment: Have you seen the Weil pairing at all? That's the obvious way to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the existence of the Weil pairing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Weil pairings yet, but at a quick glance I believe I can use this. Thank you.

Comment: If  he asks if $E(\mathbb{Q})$ has $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup, then this can't be true because $E[4](\mathbb{Q})=E[4](\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have primitive $4$-th roots. But if he asks if  $E(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$ has $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup,then isn't this possible?

Answer (score 1):

We can use $\mathbf{R}$ in place of $\mathbf{Q}$, if we like.

Draw a picture of a curve that has three real $2$-torsion points in Weierstrass form. How many of the $2$-torsion points can be the double of some other point?

Recall that every line intersects an elliptic curve in exactly three points, counting multiplicity and the point at infinity.